# What is meant by the term: The matrix is "irreducible"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, page-rank

I came across the application of the Power Method used in determining the largest eigenvalue of a matrix in solving Google's PageRank algorithm and as a summary, the entire problem lies in finding the eigenvector $v$ such that :
$$
Gv=v
$$
where $\lambda=1$ is the largest eigenvalue of $G$ with $v$ being the largest eigenvector. Here $G$ is called the Google's matrix such that :
$$
G=d*B+(1-d)*ones(n)/n
$$
$B$ is a matrix whose each column sums up to one (Stochastic matrix) or in other words $\|B\|_{1}=1$ and $d$ is a damping factor where according to Larry Page and Sergey Brin in their famous article its set to $0.85$. Moreover, $ones(n)/n$ is an $n\times n$ matrix whose all entries are $1/n$ and is a stochastic matrix. Here $n$ is the length of $B$.

In order to ensure that the power method converges a sequence of vectors to the largest eigenvector $v$, an assumption is made is that $G$ is an **irreducible** matrix with no further context to what that means. Therefore, I hope someone can assist me in explaining what it means.

Comment: In the case of this matrix, it means that the underlying graph is connected. There are not two subsets of the internet with no links between them.

Comment: Reducible means factorable into block-diagonal form. Irreducible means impossible to reduce. In other words no such factorization can be found.

Answer (score -1):

A square matrix is irreducible if it is not reducible.

See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReducibleMatrix.html